# how can i set a delayed hibernation on windows XP?

Tags: hibernate, delay, run-dialog, delayed-execution

this is working for me to set a delayed shutdown: shutdown -s -t 1000
this is working for me to hibernate my pc: %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState

but i cant delay a hibernation? (typing the above into the run dialog box)

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file using the same string you are writing in the run menu and assign it to run as a scheduled task at the time of day you want it to run.